# Stata: Use pwcompare after runmlwin

Tags: stata

I am running a multi-level model with interaction.

```
melogit outcome i.var1##i.var2 ||lev2:, or
```

I also tried using `runmlwin` as it is a lot faster.

```
runmlwin outcome i.var1##i.var2 cons,level2(lev2: cons) level1(_n:) nopause or  discrete(distribution(binomial) link(logit) denominator(cons))
```

The estimates are pretty much similar.

The problem is that I want to use `pwcompare` after`runmlwin` similar to the way I can use after `melogit`.
It is throwing an error. How can I achieve pairwise comparison?

Edited:
I was able to calculate contrast manually from e(b) table. However, I have an issue calculating confidence intervals. For a fixed-effect model, I can use e(V) to get a variance which can be used to get confidence bounds. However, if it's a random intercept model, I am unable to calculate variance. e.g. In the following example, I am trying to SE for `(urban#1) vs (urban#0)` similar to the output in pwcompare but to no avail.

```
. webuse bangladesh, clear
(Bangladesh Fertility Survey, 1989)

. 
. gen children1 = 0 if inlist(children ,0,1)
(1,050 missing values generated)

. 
. replace children1 = 1 if inlist(children ,2,3)
(1,050 real changes made)

. 
. melogit c_use i.urban##i.children1  || district:

Fitting fixed-effects model:

Iteration 0:   log likelihood = -1258.2413  
Iteration 1:   log likelihood = -1256.5543  
Iteration 2:   log likelihood = -1256.5533  
Iteration 3:   log likelihood = -1256.5533  

Refining starting values:

Grid node 0:   log likelihood = -1248.2739

Fitting full model:

Iteration 0:   log likelihood = -1248.2739  (not concave)
Iteration 1:   log likelihood = -1236.1736  
Iteration 2:   log likelihood = -1235.4412  
Iteration 3:   log likelihood = -1235.4296  
Iteration 4:   log likelihood = -1235.4296  

Mixed-effects logistic regression               Number of obs     =      1,934
Group variable:        district                 Number of groups  =         60

                                                Obs per group:
                                                              min =          2
                                                              avg =       32.2
                                                              max =        118

Integration method: mvaghermite                 Integration pts.  =          7

                                                Wald chi2(3)      =      61.28
Log likelihood = -1235.4296                     Prob > chi2       =     0.0000
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          c_use |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
          urban |
         urban  |   .7510512   .1632623     4.60   0.000     .4310631    1.071039
    1.children1 |   .5938377   .1216843     4.88   0.000     .3553409    .8323344
                |
urban#children1 |
       urban#1  |  -.1030926   .2136775    -0.48   0.629    -.5218927    .3157076
                |
          _cons |  -1.049338    .114393    -9.17   0.000    -1.273545   -.8251322
----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
district        |
      var(_cons)|   .2063726   .0705496                      .1056001    .4033108
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
LR test vs. logistic model: chibar2(01) = 42.25       Prob >= chibar2 = 0.0000

. 
. pwcompare i.urban##i.children1

Pairwise comparisons of marginal linear predictions

Margins      : asbalanced

-------------------------------------------------------------------------
                        |                                 Unadjusted
                        |   Contrast   Std. Err.     [95% Conf. Interval]
------------------------+------------------------------------------------
c_use                   |
                  urban |
        urban vs rural  |   .6995049   .1172543      .4696907    .9293191
                        |
              children1 |
                1 vs 0  |   .5422914   .1075603       .331477    .7531058
                        |
        urban#children1 |
(rural#1) vs (rural#0)  |   .5938377   .1216843      .3553409    .8323344
(urban#0) vs (rural#0)  |   .7510512   .1632623      .4310631    1.071039
(urban#1) vs (rural#0)  |   1.241796   .1639783      .9204047    1.563188
(urban#0) vs (rural#1)  |   .1572135   .1540996     -.1448162    .4592432
(urban#1) vs (rural#1)  |   .6479586   .1538558      .3464068    .9495104
(urban#1) vs (urban#0)  |   .4907451   .1765231      .1447661    .8367241
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

. 
. mat list e(V)

symmetric e(V)[10,10]
                       c_use:         c_use:         c_use:         c_use:         c_use:         c_use:         c_use:         c_use:         c_use:             /:
                          0b.             1.            0b.             1.      0b.urban#      0b.urban#      1o.urban#       1.urban#                         var(
                       urban          urban      children1      children1   0b.children1   1o.children1   0b.children1    1.children1          _cons  _cons[dis~t])
        c_use:
     0b.urban              0
      1.urban              0      .02665456
 0b.children1              0              0              0
  1.children1              0      .00885747              0      .01480706
     0b.urban#
 0b.children1              0              0              0              0              0
     0b.urban#
 1o.children1              0              0              0              0              0              0
     1o.urban#
 0b.children1              0              0              0              0              0              0              0
      1.urban#
  1.children1              0     -.02432051              0     -.01465235              0              0              0      .04565806
        _cons              0     -.00890614              0     -.00901114              0              0              0      .00873016      .01308577
            /:
          var(
_cons[dis~t])              0     -.00073136              0       .0003903              0              0              0      .00039822      -.0009874      .00497724

.
```

Comment: I have never used `runmlwin`, but the whole point  seems to be calling other software from within Stata as a convenience, so it doesn't seem surprising that the commands don't speak the same language or that `runmlwin` doesn't supply Stata with what `pwcompare` needs to work on.  "an error" is a vague report; my guess is that `pwcompare` fails very early. I don't guess at any work-around being possible here beyond using `melogit`.

Comment: Yes, pwcompare fails very early. melogit takes almost a day for model to converge and runmlwin takes 5 minutes for the same model and I have several models. This is the reason I am inclined towards using runmlwin.

Comment: @NickCox I edited my question. I am able to get estimates similar to pwcompare but have a hard time calculating SE.